# Nodeclipse Debugger stops on the first line, even after clearing all breakpoints

Tags: eclipse, node.js, debugging, nodeclipse

I believe this is a bug in the NodeClipse IDE for Eclipse. Even after I delete all the breakpoints in the IDE, the debugger stops on the first line, it is driving me nuts. At the end of the day having to look for the minuscule "Continue" button is taking a toll on my patience.

Anyone having the same issue? How did you fix this?

Here is an image of the problem :

http://joaorosilva.no-ip.org/public/stackoverflow/Screen%20Shot%202013-07-04%20at%2015.35.37.png

Comment: I have switched to jetbrains webstorm IDE and this behaviour no longer exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as "NodeClipse IDE"

There are

- nodeclipse plugin (nodeclipse-1)
- Enide (set of plugins)
- Nodeclipse NTS (Eclipse distribution)

You should have mentioned what exact version of Nodeclipse and Eclipse are you using.
I am using Nodeclipse NTS 0.4.10 (based on Eclipse 4.3 Kepler) every day now.

Just press <kbd>F8</kbd> to resume.

Since Nodeclipse 0.6 there is option to "no -break", that will use `--debug` without interrupting Node app on 1st line.

From Node wiki

> There are 2 debug related node options:
>
> node --debug[=port] NodeApp.js
>
> node --debug-brk[=port] NodeApp.js
>
> The `--debug` option will just enable remote debugger connection on given port and then start the application normally.
>    Even when debugger is connected to the running node instance later on, the script execution will not be stopped until
>    “Suspend” command is issued by Eclipse debugger. Another way to stop the execution is to browse the source code of the
>    JavaScript modules comprising the application and double click on the line number at the desired position in script to 
>    break at (most likely a callback). Once execution stops you can set/clear more breakpoints, but also inspect call stack
>    and view content of all program variables.
>
> The `--debug-brk` option is needed when your script is short lived (no time to attach debugger) and/or you want to observe 
>   the NodeApp.js execution from the very start. This option will force execution to break at the first line of the main script 
>   and wait for debugger to connect. The behavior upon connection is now different – the script is suspended and no breakpoints are set. 
>   Note that V8 engine debugger is not behaving very good when it steps over or steps into require() method (it will crash), 
>   so try to set up first breakpoint past the initial module loading. This will also enable you to set breakpoints in any of those modules as well.

That is, if `--debug` is used, than small apps and beginning of an application are impossible to debug.

Comment: I did this on Eclipse Juno. Thanks for the explanation and the tip on the shortcut, it's a temporary fix until they decide to change this behaviour I guess!

Comment: Yes, I am sure of it... They must have their reasons for not fixing this, just like we have freedom to use different technologies.

Comment: Dear @João Rocha da Silva, you see most active contributors answering to your questions :-D

Comment: Well then, here is my humble suggestion: if you are so inclined, place a tick in the settings panel in a future release to deactivate this behaviour, much like in NetBeans PHP Debugger settings Panel : "Stop on first line"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the debugger to break any line, you should select [Run As]-[Node Application], not [Debug As]-[Node Application].

Comment: Then it will not and should not stop at break-points.
The point was that debugger always enters step-by-step mode.

Comment: I don't think so. He said "the debugger stops on the first line".

Comment: What did you mean by the sentence "the debugger always enters step-by-step mode"? Did you means the debugger stops each line of all source code, not only the first line of a main source file?

Comment: I think he meant that Nodeclipse always stops on the first line, much like node-inspector, instead of running up to the first breakpoint present in the entire project.